# JHipster - Keycloak - React: I am always getting redirected to localhost:9000/oauth2/authorization/oidc when trying to register a new user

Tags: reactjs, keycloak, jhipster

I have an app built with JHipster 7.8, spring, react, keycloak.
When I try to register a user, in debug mode, it always call UserService.syncUserWithIdp... In the browser it seems to infinitly redirect to localhost:9000 and localhost:9000/oauth2/authorization/oidc  till it shows http://localhost:9000/login?error.
(update: This error was present for login also when I try to save more data about the user in database with MyCustomSupplierRepository.save(supplier)...
I am stuck, please if some more details are required tell me.
In the following my user service.java:

```
@Service
```

@Transactional
public class UserService {

```
private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserService.class);

private final UserRepository userRepository;

private final SupplierExtendedRepository supplierExtendedRepository;

private final AuthorityRepository authorityRepository;

private final CacheManager cacheManager;

public UserService(UserRepository userRepository, AuthorityRepository authorityRepository,
        CacheManager cacheManager, SupplierExtendedRepository supplierExtendedRepository) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
    this.authorityRepository = authorityRepository;
    this.cacheManager = cacheManager;
    this.supplierExtendedRepository = supplierExtendedRepository;
}

/**
 * Update basic information (first name, last name, email, language) for the
 * current user.
 *
 * @param firstName first name of user.
 * @param lastName  last name of user.
 * @param email     email id of user.
 * @param langKey   language key.
 * @param imageUrl  image URL of user.
 */
public void updateUser(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String langKey, String imageUrl) {
    SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin().flatMap(userRepository::findOneByLogin).ifPresent(user -> {
        user.setFirstName(firstName);
        user.setLastName(lastName);
        if (email != null) {
            user.setEmail(email.toLowerCase());
        }
        user.setLangKey(langKey);
        user.setImageUrl(imageUrl);
        this.clearUserCaches(user);
        log.debug("Changed Information for User: {}", user);
    });
}

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Page<AdminUserDTO> getAllManagedUsers(Pageable pageable) {
    return userRepository.findAll(pageable).map(AdminUserDTO::new);
}

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Page<UserDTO> getAllPublicUsers(Pageable pageable) {
    return userRepository.findAllByIdNotNullAndActivatedIsTrue(pageable).map(UserDTO::new);
}

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Optional<User> getUserWithAuthoritiesByLogin(String login) {
    return userRepository.findOneWithAuthoritiesByLogin(login);
}

/**
 * Gets a list of all the authorities.
 * 
 * @return a list of all the authorities.
 */
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<String> getAuthorities() {
    return authorityRepository.findAll().stream().map(Authority::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private User syncUserWithIdP(Map<String, Object> details, User user) {
    // save authorities in to sync user roles/groups between IdP and JHipster's
    // local database
    Collection<String> dbAuthorities = getAuthorities();
    Collection<String> userAuthorities = user.getAuthorities().stream().map(Authority::getName)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    for (String authority : userAuthorities) {
        if (!dbAuthorities.contains(authority)) {
            log.debug("Saving authority '{}' in local database", authority);
            Authority authorityToSave = new Authority();
            authorityToSave.setName(authority);
            authorityRepository.save(authorityToSave);
        }
    }
    // save account in to sync users between IdP and JHipster's local database
    Optional<User> existingUser = userRepository.findOneByLogin(user.getLogin());
    if (existingUser.isPresent()) {

        // if IdP sends last updated information, use it to determine if an update
        // should happen
        if (details.get("updated_at") != null) {
            Instant dbModifiedDate = existingUser.get().getLastModifiedDate();
            Instant idpModifiedDate = (Instant) details.get("updated_at");
            if (idpModifiedDate.isAfter(dbModifiedDate)) {
                log.debug("Updating user '{}' in local database", user.getLogin());
                updateUser(user.getFirstName(), user.getLastName(), user.getEmail(), user.getLangKey(),
                        user.getImageUrl());
            }
            // no last updated info, blindly update
        } else {
            log.debug("Updating user '{}' in local database", user.getLogin());

            updateUser(user.getFirstName(), user.getLastName(), user.getEmail(), user.getLangKey(),
                    user.getImageUrl());

        }
    } else { // in case of user from idp does not exist in Jhipster's database
        log.debug("Saving user '{}' in local database", user.getLogin());
        user = userRepository.save(user);
        this.clearUserCaches(user);
    }

    return user;
}

public static Supplier fillSupplierWithNewData(Supplier supplier, Map<String, Object> details, User user) {
    String country = null;
    String state = null;
    String city = null;
    String street = null;
    String phone = null;
    String businessName = null;
    String businessCategory = null;
    if (supplier.getId() != null) {
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now().plusMonths(6);
        supplier.setTrialExpiryDate(zdt);
    } else if (supplier.getTrialExpiryDate() == null) {
        supplier.setTrialExpiryDate(ZonedDateTime.now());
    }
    if (details.get("phone") != null) {
        phone = ((String) details.get("phone")).toLowerCase();
    }
    if (details.get("businessName") != null) {
        businessName = ((String) details.get("businessName")).toLowerCase();
    }
    if (details.get("businessCategory") != null) {
        businessCategory = ((String) details.get("businessCategory")).toUpperCase();
    }
    if (details.get("address") != null) {
        JSONObject addressJsonObject = (JSONObject) details.get("address");
        if (addressJsonObject != null) {
            if (addressJsonObject.get("country") != null) {
                country = ((String) addressJsonObject.get("country")).toLowerCase();
            }
            if (addressJsonObject.get("street_address") != null) {
                street = ((String) addressJsonObject.get("street_address")).toLowerCase();
            }
            if (addressJsonObject.get("city") != null) {
                city = ((String) addressJsonObject.get("city")).toLowerCase();
            }
            if (addressJsonObject.get("state") != null) {
                state = ((String) addressJsonObject.get("state")).toLowerCase();
            }
        }
    }
    Address address = new Address();
    address.setCity(city);
    address.setCountry(country);
    address.setState(state);
    address.setStreet(street);

    supplier.setFirstName(user.getFirstName());
    supplier.setLastName(user.getLastName());
    supplier.setBasinessName(businessName);
    supplier.setCategory(businessCategory == null ? null : BusinessCategory.valueOf(businessCategory));
    supplier.setPrimaryPhone(phone);
    supplier.setUserName(user.getLogin());
    supplier.setUser(user);
    supplier.addAddresses(address);

    return supplier;
}

/**
 * Returns the user from an OAuth 2.0 login or resource server with JWT.
 * Synchronizes the user in the local repository.
 *
 * @param authToken the authentication token.
 * @return the user from the authentication.
 */
@Transactional
public AdminUserDTO getUserFromAuthentication(AbstractAuthenticationToken authToken) {
    Map<String, Object> attributes;
    if (authToken instanceof OAuth2AuthenticationToken) {
        attributes = ((OAuth2AuthenticationToken) authToken).getPrincipal().getAttributes();
    } else if (authToken instanceof JwtAuthenticationToken) {
        attributes = ((JwtAuthenticationToken) authToken).getTokenAttributes();
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("AuthenticationToken is not OAuth2 or JWT!");
    }

    User user = getUser(attributes);
    user.setAuthorities(authToken.getAuthorities().stream().map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).map(authority -> {
        Authority auth = new Authority();
        auth.setName(authority);
        return auth;
    }).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
    if (user.getAuthorities() == null || user.getAuthorities().size() == 0) {
        Authority auth = new Authority();
        auth.setName(AuthoritiesConstants.USER);
    }

    return new AdminUserDTO(syncUserWithIdP(attributes, user));
}

public static User getUser(Map<String, Object> details) {
    User user = new User();
    Boolean activated = Boolean.TRUE;
    String sub = String.valueOf(details.get("sub"));
    String username = null;

    if (details.get("preferred_username") != null) {
        username = ((String) details.get("preferred_username")).toLowerCase();
    }
    // handle resource server JWT, where sub claim is email and uid is ID
    if (details.get("uid") != null) {
        user.setId((String) details.get("uid"));
        user.setLogin(sub);
    } else {
        user.setId(sub);
    }
    if (username != null) {
        user.setLogin(username);
    } else if (user.getLogin() == null) {
        user.setLogin(user.getId());
    }
    if (details.get("given_name") != null) {
        user.setFirstName((String) details.get("given_name"));
    } else if (details.get("name") != null) {
        user.setFirstName((String) details.get("name"));
    }
    if (details.get("family_name") != null) {
        user.setLastName((String) details.get("family_name"));
    }
    if (details.get("email_verified") != null) {
        activated = (Boolean) details.get("email_verified");
    }
    if (details.get("email") != null) {
        user.setEmail(((String) details.get("email")).toLowerCase());
    } else if (sub.contains("|") && (username != null && username.contains("@"))) {
        // special handling for Auth0
        user.setEmail(username);
    } else {
        user.setEmail(sub);
    }
    if (details.get("langKey") != null) {
        user.setLangKey((String) details.get("langKey"));
    } else if (details.get("locale") != null) {
        // trim off country code if it exists
        String locale = (String) details.get("locale");
        if (locale.contains("_")) {
            locale = locale.substring(0, locale.indexOf('_'));
        } else if (locale.contains("-")) {
            locale = locale.substring(0, locale.indexOf('-'));
        }
        user.setLangKey(locale.toLowerCase());
    } else {
        // set langKey to default if not specified by IdP
        user.setLangKey(Constants.DEFAULT_LANGUAGE);
    }
    if (details.get("picture") != null) {
        user.setImageUrl((String) details.get("picture"));
    }
    user.setActivated(activated);
    return user;
}

private void clearUserCaches(User user) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(cacheManager.getCache(UserRepository.USERS_BY_LOGIN_CACHE)).evict(user.getLogin());
    if (user.getEmail() != null) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(cacheManager.getCache(UserRepository.USERS_BY_EMAIL_CACHE)).evict(user.getEmail());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: 9000 is the port of BrowserSync which acts as a proxy. Have you started all 3 processes: java backend (mvnw or gradlew), webpack dev server (npm start) and KeyCloak (docker-compose) ? See https://www.jhipster.tech/development/

Comment: Yes, sure, it goes to the backend ans calls syncuserwithidp, but without stoppjng until it reachss the login error page

Comment: I think I am missing something in tbe authenticatiion or redirects flow

Comment: @GaëlMarziou
I've edited the post, notice the error occurs when I try to save some data about the user (supplier in my case).

Comment: Did you see some error in server logs? Have you tried running it under debugger?

Comment: @GaëlMarziou Yes I am running it in debug mode, but no errors are logged there,  the problem is now only on registring a new user, and solved for login when I removed a custom function that saves some user data on syncUserWithIdp (Only for login), but it is persist for registration. Question edited.

Comment: The @GetMapping("/account")   public AdminUserDTO getAccount(Principal principal) is always called.

Comment: Thank you @GaëlMarziou for you intent to help, I really appreciate that.
The problem was that I am receiving a non - activated user from getAccount(), then request is resent to getAccount() more and more times.